# Can box hedging under palm trees be affected by the palms?

Tags: trees, palm, boxwood

I've got 6 box bushes, 4 under palm trees and 2 not. The 4 that are under the palms are badly affected by something, like dust, but the 2 that aren't are fine. Could the palm trees be dropping something that is affecting the box hedging? could it just be the shadow that is killing the boxes? There is new green growth at the bottom of the bushes.

Answer (score 1):

Are there yellow structures [similar to this](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61ygCZ-yojL.jpg) hanging from the palms? If so, then what you're seeing is pollen that has been released from the trees above the boxwoods. Note that the link shows date palm pollen, so what your trees may have would probably look at least a little different.

Comment: Hi Jurp, no we haven't had anything like  that on our palms, but thank you for suggesting it